# debian stretch with mate kernel freeze with linux-image-4.9.0-16-amd64

Tags: debian, kernel-panic

A few days ago I get an update for kernel and boot it up yesterday the first time. A few minutes later my debian freezed complete. I have to use magic request to reboot my notebook.

I boot up the previous kernel und make persistentes journaling. And stresst a little while my system with showing videos on youtube. All was well.

Today another update came in

```
Start-Date: 2021-07-10  17:13:12
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Upgrade: intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20201118.1~deb9u1, 3.20210608.2~deb9u2)
End-Date: 2021-07-10  17:13:23
```

so I rebootet to the newest kernel and 5 minutes later system freeze again.

From journal:

```
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm ctr ccm vboxnetadp(O) vboxnetflt(O) snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device cmac vboxdrv(O) cpufreq_userspace cpufreq_power
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  nf_reject_ipv6 xt_hl ip6t_rt nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_addrtype nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_def
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 2604 Comm: Web Content Tainted: G           O    4.9.0-16-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.272-1
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 2350B58/2350B58, BIOS G1ET41WW (1.16 ) 05/25/2012
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: task: ffff9d97c12c4080 task.stack: ffffb59b42644000
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff85a2aaf7>]  [<ffffffff85a2aaf7>] __destroy_inode+0xf7/0x160
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb59b42647e20  EFLAGS: 00010246
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RAX: ffff9d985411e800 RBX: ffff9d97e3c541e8 RCX: 0000000000000018
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RDX: 000000000000004e RSI: ffff9d97e3c54270 RDI: 6000000000000000
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RBP: ffff9d9853e45300 R08: ffffb59b42647ca8 R09: 0000000000000000
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffff9d97eb09f658
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: R13: ffff9d9853e45300 R14: ffff9d97e3c541e8 R15: ffff9d9853e45358
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: FS:  00007fb118dd8740(0000) GS:ffff9d985e200000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: CR2: 00007fb0f9005000 CR3: 00000000c950a000 CR4: 0000000000160670
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: Stack:
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  ffff9d97e3c541e8 ffffffff85a2ab81 ffff9d97eb09f600 ffffffff85a25f6f
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  ffff9d97eb09f600 ffff9d97eb09f658 ffffffff8620bd08 ffffffff85a26162
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  ffff9d97f8d67900 0000000000000008 ffff9d97e3c541e8 ffff9d98536674e0
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85a2ab81>] ? destroy_inode+0x21/0x60
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85a25f6f>] ? __dentry_kill+0xaf/0x160
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85a26162>] ? dput+0x142/0x260
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85a0faad>] ? __fput+0x17d/0x220
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff8589941f>] ? task_work_run+0x7f/0xa0
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85803754>] ? exit_to_usermode_loop+0xa4/0xb0
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85803bd9>] ? do_syscall_64+0xe9/0x100
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  [<ffffffff85e2238e>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_swapgs+0x58/0xc6
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: Code: eb ff eb c3 48 8d b8 f8 01 00 00 f0 48 83 a8 f8 01 00 00 01 0f 85 65 ff ff ff 48 8b 80 08 02 00 00 e8 be d5 3f 00 e9 54 ff ff ff <f0> ff 0
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: RIP  [<ffffffff85a2aaf7>] __destroy_inode+0xf7/0x160
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel:  RSP <ffffb59b42647e20>
Jul 10 20:34:41 Taomon kernel: ---[ end trace 6dbf021422b06dec ]---
Jul 10 20:37:06 Taomon rtkit-daemon[853]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jul 10 20:37:06 Taomon rtkit-daemon[853]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon wpa_supplicant[1162]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 7c:ff:4d:48:cd:b6 [GTK=CCMP]
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: Xorg: Corrupted page table at address 5567d8100983
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: PGD 8000000114701067 
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: PUD 112df2067 
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: PMD b56a0067 
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: PTE 800000b0706d2067
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: 
Jul 10 20:37:41 Taomon kernel: Bad pagetable: 000d [#2] SMP
```

My notebook

```
 dmidecode -t 0
 dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: LENOVO
    Version: G1ET41WW (1.16 )
    Release Date: 05/25/2012
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 12288 kB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        EDD is supported
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 1.16
    Firmware Revision: 1.7
```

with intel gpu

Note my System is installed in bios mode (so secure boot can not be the trigger).

Is this a kernelbug?

Comment: Okay I removed virtualbox complete and check it tomorrow.

Comment: After another update from intel-microde to `3.20210608.2~deb9u2` the freezes are gone.

Comment: Good to know, but that's already the intel-microcode described in OP (`Upgrade: intel-microcode:amd64 (3.20201118.1~deb9u1, 3.20210608.2~deb9u2)`).